# What is the correct way to transfer large volumes of chemicals?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, safety, equipment

I am an engineer starting a film developing and processing lab in my house for personal use. I am currently using a bathroom, and am concerned about contaminating my chemical process and the bathroom using what seem to be accepted practices in developing labs.

Many developing chemicals (e.g. Kodak D-76) come in exact quantities to mix 1 gallon of stock solution. I will mostly be using quantities 500 mL or less, though certain chemicals will be larger arbitrary volumes.

What methods/equipment are used for transferring large volumes?

Comment: what kind of engineer?

Comment: drum pumps! If you want to get large volumes of unreactive liquid out of a barrel or other large container you can do this easily with a drum pump and transfer it into measuring cyclinders like @NotEvans posted.

Comment: @A.K. Electrical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the chemicals in question aren't air sensitive (i.e. theres no need for an inert atmosphere), a measuring cylinder would suit your needs.

They're available in glass and various plastics, in sizes upto around 3000 mL. The glass ones are generally better as theres less risk of the chemicals reacting with the glass compared to with plastic, but it really does depend on what you're using.

Once you're done with the measuring cylinder, just rinse it with water (into a suitable toxic waste container if the chemicals cannot go down the drain, which I suspect they can't), and leave it to dry somewhere (else put it in a warm oven for an hour or so).

[image]

Comment: What is the correct way to get liquid into the cylinders if the bottles are too full to pour?

Comment: @JimmyStrates: A large pipette would do (but not overly convenient for large volumes), some kind of siphon would be best!